# Copy all rows except a specific row to text file

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write all the data from `sample_data.txt` to `t_sdata.txt` except the row where the string inputted by the user on the `textbox (txt_key)` can be found.

```
[sample data]
key,item,qty
0001,Apple,5
0002,Orange,10
0003,Grapes,15
```

so if i input `0002` in the textbox, `t_sdata.txt` should contain:

```
[sample output data]
key,item,qty
0001,Apple,5
0003,Grapes,15
```

this is what I have right now which currently doesn't save anything:

```
string plist = @"sample_data.txt";
string tdata = @"t_sdata.txt";
var dataline = File.ReadAllLines(plist)
    .SkipWhile(l => !l.StartsWith(txt_key.Text))
    .TakeWhile(l => !l.StartsWith(txt_key.Text) && l != null);
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(tdata))
{
    foreach (var lines in dataline)
    {
        if (dataline == null)
            w.WriteLine(lines);
    }
}
```

I've been playing around the `SkipWhile/TakeWhile` bit but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

*(not sure if relevant) note: the key can be of different lengths and that 01 can have a different data from 001*

Comment: Not sure anything would happen here, since you're online writing a line to the StreamWriter if (dataline == null). The logic says that for all lines in dataline, if dataline is null write a line - doesn't make sense, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solutions seems complicated, you don't really care about which line it is that does not get selected into the new file:

```
string plist = @"sample_data.txt";
string tdata = @"t_sdata.txt";
string input = "0002";

File.WriteAllLines(tdata, File.ReadLines(plist).Where(line => !line.StartsWith(input)));
```

A slightly better solution for your file format would be to actually separate the different fields, so `02` and `5` do *not* match `0220,Test,5`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(tdata, File.ReadLines(plist)
                              .Where(line => line.Split(new char[]{ ',' }).First() != input));
```

Comment: Nice, would suggest perhaps .StartsWith() would be better than .Contains() in this case?

Comment: @MartinDavies Depends on what the OP wants, the code says `StartsWith`, his text says "can be found"... I guess the OP will figure it out.

Comment: Probably you mean `File.WriteAllLines`

Comment: Indeed - in fact, StartsWith(input + ",") would be better I imagine, since the key can be different lengths.

Comment: @MartinDavies You are right, I added an improved statement.